# Realloc crashes my program in reading binary file function

Tags: c, realloc

So i have this fuction in C to read data from a binary file to a dynamic array. When i run it it crashes, i tried to put some printf to know where it is stuck and seems like it's when I try to do a realloc. 
I just can't find anything wrong. Hope somebody can help me.

```
tipoEmprestimo *lerFichBin_Emprestimos(tipoEmprestimo *vetorEmprestimos,int *quantEmprestimos)
{
    int quantlidos;
    FILE *ficheiro;


    ficheiro=fopen("emprestimos.dat","rb");

    if (ficheiro == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nNao foi possivel ler o ficheiro!");
        free(vetorEmprestimos);
        vetorEmprestimos=NULL;
        *quantEmprestimos=0;
    }
    else
    {

        quantlidos=fread(&quantEmprestimos,sizeof(int),1,ficheiro);
        if (quantlidos != 1)
        {
            printf("\nErro ao ler ficheiro!");
        }
        vetorEmprestimos=realloc(vetorEmprestimos,(*quantEmprestimos)*sizeof(tipoEmprestimo));


        if (vetorEmprestimos == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nErro ao reservar memoria!");

        }
        else
        {

            quantlidos=fread(vetorEmprestimos,sizeof(tipoEmprestimo),*quantEmprestimos,ficheiro);
            if(quantlidos != *quantEmprestimos)
            {
                printf("\nErro ao ler ficheiro!");
            }
        }

    }
    fclose(ficheiro);
return vetorEmprestimos;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], along with sample input which provokes the misbehaviour. Ideally find a text input, otherwise describe the (hopefully few) non-text parts of the needed input.

Comment: This sample code would be easier to read if everything would be named in English. However, I believe there are two main reasons why a `realloc()` may fail: 1.) the amount of memory to allocate is not available 2.) the pointer to memory for realloc doesn't result from a previous allocation and isn't `NULL`. These are the things I would check in debugger first.

Answer (score 2):

Among possible reasons

- *vetorEmprestimos* is not initialized when you call the realloc
- *vetorEmprestimos* point to the stack when you call the realloc
- *vetorEmprestimos* point to a constant memory area  when you call the realloc

Answer (score 2):

> I just can't find anything wrong

**Save time**, let the compiler help you.

Good compilers, fully enabled, will complain about all sorts of things:

```
In function 'lerFichBin_Emprestimos':
warning: conversion to 'int' from 'size_t {aka long unsigned int}' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
     quantlidos = fread(&quantEmprestimos, sizeof(int), 1, ficheiro);
                  ^~~~~
warning: conversion to 'long unsigned int' from 'int' may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
         (*quantEmprestimos) * sizeof(tipoEmprestimo));
                             ^
warning: conversion to 'size_t {aka long unsigned int}' from 'int' may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
           *quantEmprestimos, ficheiro);
           ^
warning: conversion to 'int' from 'size_t {aka long unsigned int}' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
       quantlidos = fread(vetorEmprestimos, sizeof(tipoEmprestimo),
                    ^~~~~
Finished building: ../round.c
```

Fixing the above may/may not solve your issue but it demonstrates that good coding practices were first employed before turning to Stackoverflow.

---

### Why read a pointer?

The below is trying to read a pointer and not an `int`.  This is a huge coding mistake.

```
int *quantEmprestimos
...
... fread(&quantEmprestimos, ...
```

Certainly code should read an `int`.

```
//        v--------No & 
... fread( quantEmprestimos, ...
```

**Avoid explicit types**

Rather than code types and perhaps get it wrong - as OP did, use the size of the referenced object.

```
//               points to an `int *`, mis-matched size
// quantlidos=fread(&quantEmprestimos, sizeof(int),1,ficheiro);

//                                   matched size                 
quantlidos = fread(quantEmprestimos, sizeof *quantEmprestimos, 1, ficheiro);
```

---

**Rethink error handling**

Should `fread()` not return 1, what is the value of `quantEmprestimos` used in `realloc()`?  On error, code still uses `quantEmprestimos`.  `stdio` is often line  buffered and thus the lack of an error message is not an indication of success.  Use **stderr** for error output as it is flushed on each write.

> `quantEmprestimos` is uninitialized - could be anything!

```
// OP's code with problems
quantlidos = fread(&quantEmprestimos, sizeof(int), 1, ficheiro);
if (quantlidos != 1) {
  printf("\nErro ao ler ficheiro!");
}
vetorEmprestimos = realloc(vetorEmprestimos, (*quantEmprestimos) * sizeof(tipoEmprestimo));
```

Alternative code

```
quantlidos = fread(quantEmprestimos, sizeof *quantEmprestimos, 1, ficheiro);
if (quantlidos != 1) {
  // printf("\nErro ao ler ficheiro!");
  fprintf(stderr, "\nErro ao ler ficheiro!");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  // or do something other than continue on.
}
vetorEmprestimos = realloc(vetorEmprestimos, sizeof *vetorEmprestimos * *quantEmprestimos);
```